# PHP client for SOAP web service

Tags: php, soap, jax-ws, soap-client

I have Java code that exactly does this:

```
// Create a "Service" instance
Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = createDispatch();
// Build a SOAP request
SOAPMessage request = buildMessage(username, password);
// Invoke the request
SOAPMessage response = dispatch.invoke(request);
```

I want to do the same thing using PHP code. I m new to PHP and I came across a standard SoapClient class but it seems to work with WSDL files. 
What I need is building a SOAP message with various properties in the code and then give service port name etc..

What is the PHP library that I should use? (similar to Java API for XML Web Services)
Can I do the job with standard SoapClient PHP lib class?

I need help from experienced PHP users. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with the built in SoapClient. See the documentation on SoapClient::__soapCall()
http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

From the examples on that page:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://localhost/soap.php",
                                     'uri'      => "http://test-uri/"));
$client->__soapCall("SomeFunction", array($a, $b, $c));
```

Comment: When I call "SomeFunction" with some parameters, the resulting XML is something like:

Comment: When I call "SomeFunction" with some parameters, the resulting XML is something like:    <SomeFunction> <param0 xsi:type="string">abc</param0></SomeFunction>   but I need named parameters with namespaces. For example, I want the resulting XML like this: <SomeFuction><wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <a:EndpointReference>
          <a:Address>some address</a:Address>
        </a:EndpointReference>
      </wsp:AppliesTo></SomeFunction>

Comment: When I call "SomeFunction" with some parameters, the resulting XML is something like:    <SomeFunction> <param0 xsi:type="string">abc</param0></SomeFunction>   but I need named parameters with namespaces. For example, I want the resulting XML like this: <SomeFuction><wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <a:EndpointReference>
          <a:Address>some address</a:Address>
        </a:EndpointReference>
      </wsp:AppliesTo></SomeFunction>    How can I create parameters with names and namespaces of names? I couldnt find any information in the docs.